# Call function with reference

Tags: java, javacpp

I'm trying to call the following `c++` function:

```
uint32_t FunctionName(uint32_t *arg1,uint32_t *arg2,uint32_t *arg3)
```

but I cannot find a way to map this in `Javacpp`.

How do I pass the pointer reference to the function, and how do I retrieve the changed values from the passed pointers afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work just fine:

```
import com.googlecode.javacpp.*;
import com.googlecode.javacpp.annotation.*;

@Platform(include="lib.h", link="lib")
public class Lib {
    static { Loader.load(); }

    public static native int FunctionName(@Cast("uint32_t*") int[] arg1,
                                          @Cast("uint32_t*") int[] arg2,
                                          @Cast("uint32_t*") int[] arg3);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arg1 = new int[SIZE1], arg2 = new int[SIZE2], arg3 = new int[SIZE3];
        int ret = FunctionName(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        // do what you need to do with the arguments
    }
}
```